# How to deal with crashes in the middle of a B+ tree operation?

Tags: indexing, data-structures, recovery, b-tree

In between B+ tree operations, the tree is in a valid state, in the sense that the properties of a B+ tree are satisfied. However, during an operation on the B+ tree, those same properties will probably not be satisfied (at least not all of them). So if the process that operates on the B+ tree crashes or is killed, or the computer dies (maybe there is a power outage), when a tree operation is going on and the tree therefore is in an invalid state, how do you get the tree into a valid state again? That is, how do you recover from messing the tree up by only performing part of an operation?

**Edit:** I wrote this question with B+ trees in mind, but I'm really wondering how to do this for any tree data structure that uses the disk, so an answer of how to do this for B-trees would also be fine since B+ trees and B-trees are so similar.

Comment: To anyone voting for this question to be closed because it "needs more focus," meaning it includes multiple questions in one, in what way do you think that this question asks multiple things? (Sometimes I get the feeling that some people vote for questions to be closed just because they cannot answer them and therefore find them uncomfortable.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_Recovery_and_Isolation_Exploiting_Semantics

Comment: @boneill Interesting! I was thinking about logging the planned transactions (atomic system operations, such as moving a file or creating a folder) for the operation too, and keeping track of which transactions had been performed (potentially also checking whether the transaction currently taking place according to the log had finished), so that the series of transactions could simply be continued once the process had been restarted. (Although it seems ARIES undoes some transactions.) I was wondering if there were some simpler way but maybe this is the only option.